# Rose flowers distorted

Tags: flowers, pests, roses

[image][MMe Hardy 1] [Mme Hardy 2]- English rose in pot.Distortion in bud through to full flower, except they do not open due to this virus [?] or pest.Flower buds normally have a greenish centre that opens out to white and a very full bloom.Any ideas as to what has affected the rose ?Can it be effectively treated to fully recover or does the plant need to be burnt and replaced ?Thank you.

Acknowledge 2Mb limit but can only upload one compressed image.[Thanks Stephie]
The image shows a bud that is probably atypical of the normal flower, with the green centre. As the fuller flower shows the opening bloom distorts to one side as it tries to enlarge.

Plant has been in pot for about a year as relative has not decided where to plant. Rose flowered normally last year. In thumb-size bigger pot than that in which it was delivered from David Austin rose supplier. Has received regular feeding/watering. Realise it would be far happier and healthier in the ground.
Thank you.

Comment: We really need a photo - but you can add more information which might help. How long have you had the rose? How long has it been in the same pot? How big is the rose and how big is the pot? Has it ever flowered normally since you got it?

Comment: Welcome! The system is perfectly fine with.jpeg, but balks at too large images. Stick to < 2MB and you should be fine.